# Correct and elegant formatting/syntax of a Javascript snippet

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

The question I would like to ask is if the Javascript snippet below is well formatted and structered in terms of Javascript/jQuery syntax, readability and speed.

The function of this piece of code is to provide a tabbed interface where through clicking the tabs different parts of content are shown. I could of course use a plugin, however I'd like to keep it simple. It works fine the way I wrote it now, but I would like to know if there are improvements to be made in order to learn a correct style and manner of coding.

```
// Wrap in anonymous function to not pollute the global namespace
(function() {
    // Hide all wrappers. 
    // If javascript is disabled then all wrappers have to be visible.
    $('#main .wrapper').hide();

    // Show selected wrapper. This class is set in the HTML that is loaded.
    // The wrapper has the id of the html, perhaps using href is better?
    var html = $('.nav a.selected').html().toLowerCase();
    $('#main #' + html).show();

    // Show selected wrapper on click event
    $('.nav a').click(function(){
        // Remove selected class all tabs
        $('.nav a').removeClass('selected');

        // Hide all wrappers and remove selected class from all wrappers
        $('#main .wrapper').hide();

        // Add selected class to new tab
        $(this).addClass('selected');

        //Show selected wrapper
        var html = $(this).html().toLowerCase();
        $('#main #' + html).show();

        return false;
    });
}());
```

I hope you can give me some advise and suggestions for correct and elegant coding. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks fine to me. Is there something specific you're not sure about?

Comment: This is a perfect question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think this is more http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions ? Unless you have an error or something in your script you need help with

Comment: Formatting meets my requirements. Comments on every line aren't really to my liking. I think that comments should be reserved for lines that aren't self-explanatory to a competent programmer in the language/library used, or to explain the "why" not the "what." So `$(this).addClass('selected');` probably doesn't require a comment.

Comment: Only thing I see is `function(){` should be `function() {` - Wow I'm picky.

Comment: There's no way to answer a question like that. Every developer has their own style of writing code. As long as it's neat and efficient and well commented, you're good. The code above looks fine, so don't scrutinize it too much.

Comment: @MikeChristensen actually it should be function () { since there is no function name.

Comment: Thanks justnS and Tessmore, i'll look into it. @drdwilcox: Comments are indeed superfluous.

Comment: @AutoSponge - Ah yes even better :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

None of the selectors are optimized for speed or cached.  As jQuery goes, I've seen worse and it will probably work fine.  As high-performance, professional JavaScript goes, it gets a D-.

```
//side comments are not really there in prod code, this is just for example purposes
//this code assumes the DOM nodes in main wrapper have no ids and can not get them, obviously ids make a huge difference
$(function () { //make sure the document is ready, not needed if you place in <script> at the bottom
    //single var statement validates JSLint
    "use strict";
    var doc = document,
        main = doc.getElementById("main"), //faster than sizzle
        $main = $(main), //faster instantiation of jQuery
        $wrapper = $main.children(".wrapper"), //faster than find, use if possible
        $nav = $(".nav"), //cached
        html;
    //initialize
    $wrapper.hide();
    html = $nav.children(".selected").eq(0).html().toLowerCase(); //stop on first
    $(doc.getElementById(html)).show();
    //add handler
    $nav.delegate("a", "click", function () { //delegate outperforms multiple handlers
        var $this = $(this); //cached
        if ($this.is(".selected")) {
            return false; //return early if this is already selected
        }
        $this.siblings(".selected").eq(0).removeClass("selected");  //you shouldn't need to find more than one
        $this.addClass("selected");
        $wrapper.hide();
        //TODO add ids
        $(doc.getElementById($this.html().toLowerCase())).show();
        return false;
    });
});
```

If you want to work on your performance, get very familiar with the work of Nick Zackas and other performance gurus who do presentations and write books on the subject.  Rely as little as possible on jQuery.  Use JSPerf religiously.  Question everything you write and leave comments when you're unsure or think it can be done better in future implementations.

Good luck to you, the results are worth the journey.

Comment: -1: I really don't see how this is even the least bit constructive.

Comment: Not sure about the downvotes... Too many ppl don't understand performance I guess.  I suggested optimized selectors and caching them.  I shouldn't have to google that for the op.

Comment: doesn't answer the question in any way.

Comment: @KaeVerens then tell me what noob mistake was made with #main

Comment: A D- :p. I'm quite curious about the writing Javascript professionally. Of course jQuery then would not be a good choice for ultimate preformance. Do you have some good sources which would guide me in the right direction? I'll google it as well

Comment: (I didn't downvote, but) if reasonably formatted code that works but could be improved gets a D- then by comparison your answer gets an F.

Comment: @Autosponge, if you're referring to the fact that the OP didn't bother caching the jQuery objects, then yes, that's an optimisation issue, but if you read the question, it was about whether the code was well structured and formatted; it was not a request for a critique.

Comment: @AutoSponge: Just explaining what's wrong without pointing in the right direction is almost useless. It would take no time for you to show one or two examples of how to optimize selectors and caching their results, and it wouldn't have got downvotes.

Comment: @KaeVerens: The question does mention: `in terms of Javascript/jQuery syntax, readability and speed.`

Comment: gimme a few minutes, I'll post a full rewrite in a manner I would approve during code review.

Comment: Yes the code is pretty typical jQuery DOM coupled spaghetti and the selectors are just horrible (readability-wise and just look at :`'#main #' + html` ...) which affects the beauty of it for me but I think the question was about formatting (ie tabs vs spaces), even so +1 from me..

Comment: why bother? the OP didn't ask for a review... the code /is/ well-formatted and structured. in terms of speed, the structure and formatting are of little-to-no consequence. Your whole argument here is based on a single word which might have slipped out accidentally. If @Ruben had wanted someone to critique the actual code and not just the formatting, that's what would have been asked for...

Comment: Critique is welcome as well, but perhaps codereview.stackexchange.com is a better place for it

Comment: @Ruben sorry for my short response before, but I was on the iPad and couldn't really rewrite it.  However, with the update to my post I hope you can see what I'm doing.  The biggest mistake is not using a .ready call to make sure your DOM material is there.  The other stuff comes with experience.  If you can control the DOM structure, make your nav links use ids and cache the ids with their relative DOM wrappers.  That way you only do one DOM query per link (as needed).  That type of caching is typical in good/lazy js.

Answer (score 0):

looks fine to me. but in one case, you have `function() {` and in another, `function(){`.

best way to figure these things out is to use a checker. for example, I use phpcs for PHP-work, using the Pear coding standard (with some minor modifications)

Comment: Thanks Kae, you know a good one for Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Looks good. A few things:

1. From the looks of it, the *text* of the link controls the div that's shown? That seems a little like a case of being cleverer than you need to be. I agree `href` is better.
2. I think the lines:

   ```
   $('.nav a').click(function(){
     $('.nav a').removeClass('selected');
   ```

   are a little confusing on first reading. Something like this:

   ```
   $('.nav a').click(function(){
     $(this).siblings('a').removeClass('selected');
   ```

   is a little more verbose, but also more readable (in my opinion).
3. Don't use `return false` to override default event behaviour. Use `.preventDefault()` instead (see here for more: http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/)

   ```
   $('.nav a').click(function(e){
     //...
     e.preventDefault();
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

just a few suggestions:

- do not use the element's inner HTML to decide which tab to show, this will fire back when you want to change the text of the tab, or if you ever need to localize your UI. use a `data-` attribute instead. `$('#main').find($(this).attr('data-tab-id')).show()`
- use event delegation instead of attaching one event per `<a>` tag. (use ".delegate" for jQuery < 1.7, or ".on" for the latest jQuery)
- do not call `.removeClass` on elements that do not need it, you can save a few useless internal DOM queries if you just do `$('.nav a.selected').removeClass('selected');`, or even better use `.siblings` like this: `$(this).siblings('.selected').removeClass('selected')` so that you don't need to store yet another reference to "nav a" and simply let the DOM dictate what to do.